# Trying to get numbers from keypress document, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

it seems simple, but I couldn't figure how to intercept numbers on javascript  from Document DOM

```
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == xx) {
            alert();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers are 48 through 57, so...

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
        alert('You pressed ' + (key - 48));
    }
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ5CY/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox, because for `keypress`, you need to use `charCode` in Firefox (`keyCode` is always zero in a `keypress` in Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Keypress events yield a keyCode of 0 in Firefox, and the ASCII character value everywhere else. Keypress events yield a charCode of the ASCII character value in Firefox. Therefore, you should use `(e.keyCode || e.charCode)` to get the character value.

Also note that your code also wouldn't work because `alert` should accept one argument. In Firefox, at least, calling `alert` with no arguments throws an exception.

With those two issues fixed, your code will now be:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.keyCode || e.charCode) == <number from 48..57 inclusive>) {
        alert('something');
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRrk6/

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter');}
    });`
replace 13 with the keys code, see here for details:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

[image: JavaScript Event KeyCode Test Page view from link below]

you should notice the differences between events **[ keyCode, charCode, which ]**
and this test page affected by the browser i.e i tested it on **safari** 
the **onKeyPress** always empty

[JavaScript Event KeyCode Test Page](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)